# How do I use a format specifier to print previously defined operators (+-%/)

Tags: c

I'm very new to programming and have been using "C Programming for Absolute Beginners" to ease myself into C language. Currently stuck on this exercise and I'm literally one step away from completing it.

I am attempting to create a math quiz generator with 2 numbers below 100 and random operators(+-*/)
The problem I'm facing right now is that I can't seem to print out the operator that I previously defined, it shows up as blank.

I've tried to assign the operator instead (single '=') but it would end up assigning ASCII value eg, * becomes 42

I've also tried assigning a char variable to use %c but that doesn't seem to be working too. When I run the code its always blank.

Please help :(

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
 int iQ1;
 int iQ2;
 int iOperator;
 char cOperator;
 int iInput;
 int answer;
 srand(time(0));
 iOperator = rand()%4+1;

 printf("%i\n", iOperator);  //randomizing works fine
 printf("Ready to do some Math?\n");

 //Randomize Q1
 iQ1 = ((rand() % 100) +1);

 //Randomize Q2
 iQ2 = ((rand() % 100) +1);

 //Randomize Operator 
 if (iOperator == 1) { cOperator == '+'; }
 else if (iOperator == 2) { cOperator == '-'; }
 else if (iOperator == 3) { cOperator == '*'; }
 else if (iOperator == 4) { cOperator == '/'; }

 //Display Question

 printf("What is %i %c %i?\n", iQ1,cOperator,iQ2);
 scanf("%i", &iInput);


 //Determine Answers for different Operators

 switch (iOperator)
 {
 case 1:
 answer = iQ1 + iQ2; break;

 case 2:
 answer = iQ1 - iQ2; break;

 case 3:
 answer = iQ1 * iQ2; break;

 case 4:
 answer = iQ1 / iQ2; break;
 }

 if (answer == iInput) { printf ("You are right! Congratulations!\n"); }
 if (answer != iInput) { printf ("You are wrong! Better luck next time\n"); }

}
```

[This is what it looks like when I run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMBaY.png)

Comment: == for comparison, = for assignment. cOperator = '+';

Comment: I would be shocked if you (a) had warnings enabled and (b) they *didn't* flag those non-assignments with "expression has no effect" or similar warnings. If you don't have them enabled, lesson learned. Turn them on, turn them up, and consider them errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comments `==` should be `=` when assigning:

```
if (iOperator == 1) { cOperator = '+'; }
else if (iOperator == 2) { cOperator = '-'; }
else if (iOperator == 3) { cOperator = '*'; }
else if (iOperator == 4) { cOperator = '/'; }
```

Also turning warnings on might have helped you, see example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b109b3c77141e1d6) 
Depending on environment and compiler it would be `-Wall` and `-Wextra` (for gcc and clang) or /W4 for VS.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Now I just gotta figure out what warnings are and how to turn them on...!

Answer (score 0):

In the `if` code inside the blocks you should assign with `=` and not compare with `==`